# MAD & Standard Deviation

Tags: standard-deviation, poisson-distribution, mad

Am I correct in saying that you can only use the formula for approximating the standard deviation from MAD, i.e

$$\text{SD } = K \times \text{ MAD }$$

if you know the actual probability distribution?

I have seen in a previous post that $K \approx 1.48$ for the normal distribution.

What is it for the Poisson distribution?

I have also seen an expression for $K = 1.25$.

Comment: I expect you intend median absolute deviation from the median when you write MAD, but not every author is consistent in what MAD stands for so we should be explicit. Could you edit your question to say which "MAD" you mean? When you say you have "also seen an expression for K = 1.25", what expression/ where, and for which distribution? Assuming you do mean the median absolute deviation from the median, that's not going to be a simple function of $\lambda$ in the case of the Poisson, though approximations may be possible.

Comment: Thanks Glen for your interest...............The expression I saw on a previous post was  SD = 1.48 x MAD for the normal distribution
I am not sure now whether this referred to Mean or Median
The other reference I have is from some OLD training notes on spare parts usage (circ 1972) is as follows:
For the normal or nearly normal distribution 
 Std Dev = 1.25 x MAD
In this case MAD is the Mean Absolute Deviation.  Where does the 1.25 come from?  and what if the data set is not normally distributed.  Does that mean you dont use MAD.  Appreciate your comments

Comment: The mean absolute deviation from the mean (sometimes called the mean deviation) tends to be larger than the median absolute deviation from the median - you must be absolutely clear about which quantity you want to use, because their behavior is very different -- you can't interchange them! The population value of the mean deviation at the normal is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}\,}\sigma\,\approx \,0.79788\,\sigma$. Consequently if you knew a good estimate of the population mean deviation (MD) for a normal population, one for the population sd would be $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\approx 1.253$ times as large.

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeanDeviation.html .... If you want me to discuss the mean deviation for the Poisson as well, you'd need to modify the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that you're interested in the median absolute deviation from the median.

The ratio of SD/MAD is different for each distribution.

All normal distributions have the same ratio, but for Poisson distributions the ratio depends on the Poisson parameter.

Note that if your data are really Poisson, an actual confidence interval for the *population* sd ($\sqrt{\lambda}$) would be best obtained by generating a corresponding interval for $\lambda$ (i.e. based on the sample mean) and then taking the square roots of the limits. As such I'll focus on using $k\times$MAD as a quick approximation for the sample SD though many of the comments would carry over to using it to estimate $\sqrt{\lambda}$.

It turns out that for large samples the asymptotic value for $k$ (that for the normal) works pretty well for a wide range of cases for $\lambda$, as long as the sample MAD is not too small.

I undertook a small simulation study.

For example, when I simulated samples from a very wide range of $\lambda$ values for n=100, I found that $k=1.48$ was pretty good, and that - as long as the MAD was at least 2.5 - the sample standard deviation tended to be within (0.8,1.3)$\times$1.48$\times$MAD more than 90% of the time (the exact performance depends on how you distribute your $\lambda$ values but didn't seem highly sensitive to it). I'd probably lean toward making $k$ just a little smaller but the variation about it is pretty large so it really doesn't matter all that much.

[$k=1.48$ was also reasonable for estimating the population SD, but it looks like the suggested bounds would need to be somewhat wider.]

However for small sample sizes (e.g. at n=10) the MAD was very variable and didn't perform well; the standard deviation will almost always exceed the MAD, so the MAD itself provides a good lower bound, but unless the MAD was quite large the sample SD might reasonably easily be 5+ times as large as the MAD, and while there isn't really any good choice of $k$, you would probably want a smaller value than 1.48 when the MAD is large enough to try it.

In short: for large samples and MAD at least 2.5, the normal value ($k=1.48$) seems to be adequate. For small samples or MAD below 2.5, I wouldn't be keen to use MAD this way, but you can reasonably assume that the sample SD is at least $1\times$MAD

Comment: Thanks GLEN I am currently on holiday in Spain, but a lot of food for thought. So need to study your info and perhaps do some examples myself. If need be maybe I can contact you privately on a paying. basis Regards dave@ramsoftuk.com